# macro to copy the certain part of data set - doesn't work properly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which scans for specific header located somewhere in the "Our Data" sheet. When it finds the header it copies the header plus the data range until the last value. After that it should copy it to "Calculations" sheet in the first empty row. However, this code doesn't work when properly when next to searched header we have some other values. Then it grabs everything.

*Example:
I want to find "Company Type". In the "Our Data" sheet it looks like this:*

```
|Target Profile Breakdown | Company Type | NAICS Description | NAICS code |
|                         |              |                   |            |
|                         |              |                   |            |
|                         |              |                   |            |
```

*Then the code copies all 4 data sets (Target profile breakdown, Company type, NAICS     descr., NAICS code) to the "Calculations" sheet.* 
Where is the mistake in my code?

**CODE:**

```
Sub testing()
Sheets("Our Data").Activate
  Dim rngAddress As Range
  Set rngAddress = Range("A1:ZZ66666").Find("Company Type")
  If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Company Type column was not found."
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).CurrentRegion.Copy
  Sheets("Calculations").Activate
Range("IV1").Select
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove `CurrentRegion` from your code which should solve your problems.